# Diagonalization of symmetric matrices in julia yields strange results

Tags: matrix, julia

I would like to understand what is going on with my program in julia. The issue is the following: I have a symmetric non-negative matrix which I diagonalize using

```
egvals, egvecs = eig(H_mat)
```

By a theorem, my matrix should have a maximum eigenvalue which is associated a non-negative eigenvector. The H_mat has a further trick, its first column and row has an entry filled with zeros.

Diagonalization yields a maximum positive eigenvalue E_max, in fact it is the last eigenvalue because julia arranges the eigenvalues in order up to the biggest, but my eigenvector associated with E_max does not have all its entries zero or positive (i.e. they have negative entries)

```
egvecs[:,end] # Some or several components ii, egvecs[ii,end]<0
```

This is the matrix from I don't get proper results, for instance:

```
[0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 1.414213562373095 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.414213562373095 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 0.0 1.7320508075688774 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.7320508075688774 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 1.414213562373095 0.0 0.0 2.0 0.0 1.414213562373095 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.7320508075688774 0.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.414213562373095 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.414213562373095 0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.414213562373095 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.0 0.0 3.0 1.7320508075688774 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.414213562373095 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.7320508075688774 3.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.7320508075688774 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 1.414213562373095 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.414213562373095 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.7320508075688774 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 1.414213562373095 0.0 0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.414213562373095 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 1.414213562373095 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.414213562373095 0.0 1.414213562373095 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.414213562373095 0.0 3.0 1.414213562373095 0.0 1.414213562373095 1.414213562373095 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.7320508075688774 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.414213562373095 3.0 0.0 0.0 2.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.414213562373095 0.0 1.414213562373095 0.0 0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.0 0.0 1.414213562373095 0.0 0.0 3.0 1.0 1.7320508075688774
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.414213562373095 2.0 0.0 1.0 3.0 1.7320508075688774
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.7320508075688774 1.7320508075688774 3.0]
```

(Should be a 20X20 matrix)

Comment: Tried a random `H_mat` with the properties you state and the max eigenvalue is associated with an eigenvector with all non-negative values.  Can you provide your `H_mat`?

Comment: Done, I think you can safely copy paste it in julia

Comment: Very curious.  Rather than `H_mat`, have a look at the `eig` results for `s=svd(H_mat);eig(s[1] * diagm(s[2]) * s[3]')`.  Other than small precision issues, the property you state seems to hold.

Comment: Also have a look at `eig(H_mat ^ 2)`.  Property seems to hold here as well.

Comment: Could it be because of the sparsity of the matrix?

Comment: Hmmm, seems my knowledge of Linear Algebra is fading and/or has some holes in it. [Eigenvectors are defined up to a phase, i.e. if $Av=\lambda v then e^{i\theta}v$ is also an eigenvector, and specifically so is $-v$.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Useful_facts_regarding_eigenvectors).  So feel free to rotate/negate.  Julia's negated `eig`-vectors are legit *and* fir your theory. [Kinda wished I'd have researched/relearned this before I chimed in.]  8-)

Comment: So, in summary, Julia's `eig` results really aren't "strange".  They're just not the preferred form to fit your theory.

Comment: I think that you're saying hermitian matrices, with off-diagonal elements complex elements. This in fact happens, but it think it is not the case  for real matrices. Using your reasoning the phase should be a complex number, which do not have much sense for this case.

Comment: (Ok put a global sin or cos in front of the eigenvector, this does not give you that all the elements of the eigenvector are all real, if they're mixed between positive and negative numbers).

Comment: Have a look at `(H_mat * -egvecs[:,end]) ./ -egvecs[:,end]` and `(H_mat * exp(pi/4*im) * egvecs[:,end]) ./ (exp(pi/4*im) * egvecs[:,end])`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs The comments were folded so I didn't see your "Hmmm" comment before now.

Comment: @andreasnoackjensen  No worries.  Your answer is better than my "wanderings".  Enjoyed the LinAlg refresh and Julia verification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eigenvectors are only determined up to proportionality because the requirement is that they solve `(A - lambda*I)v = 0` and if `v1` solves the equation, then also `v2 = -v1` does. In the symmetric case, it is standard to normalize all the vectors to one, but that still leaves the sign undetermined. Therefore the theorem you are using must say something like that the vector corresponding to the largest values **can be chosen** such that it has non-negative elements. Indeed, I get that the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of your matrix has non-positive elements.

`julia> eig(A) |> t -> all(t[2][:,indmax(t[1])] .<= 0)
true`

Comment: Yeah I just noticed it also. It's a little bit tricky because you see in the components of the eigenvector numbers like these -3.4404941487182017e-19, 0.22222222222222252. So it would appear that your eigenvector has mixed positive and negative numbers.

Comment: That is true, but I think that is unavoidable with floating point numbers.

Comment: Agreed, but at first sight it gave me the wrong impression. Anyway my eyes were open. Thanks for the answers